# Sum Conditional Logic RDLC

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc

I want to make sum of amount base on rate.

[image]

Comment: You need to add more details on how this two bottom lines are added. Are the 0.45 and 5.00 rate values hard-coded? Do you use grouping?

Comment: yeah, i make a group. it work after i use Comparison "like". i use comparison "=" before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me,

**=Sum(IIF(Fields!Rate.Value Like "0.45%", Fields!Amount.Value, Nothing), "Group1")**

Comment: Unless this is just some student assignment, the expression you are using sounds like a terrible idea.